# Problem with displaying brackets in fractions

Tags: brackets, fractions, size

I need display fraction with multiple levels and brackets in some levels. If i use standart left, right constructions, i have ugly fraction. I have a lot of empty place in brackets. Below you see example and tex code. What do I need to change to correct display this fraction?

[image: Text]

```
\frac{y_0}{x_0} +\cfrac{k_0}{\cfrac{x_0}{\left(
\cfrac{y_1}{x_1}+\cfrac{k_1}{\cfrac{x_1}{\left(
\cfrac{y_2}{x_2}+\cfrac{k_2}{\left(
\ddots + \cfrac{k_{n-1}}{
\cfrac{x_{n-1}y_n}{x_n}}\right)}\right)}}\right)}}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome. In my opinion, mathematically speaking, these brackets are useless.

Comment: One idea is to use the `pmatrix` env instead of the `\left(...\right)` pairs.

Comment: I've never seen continued fractions with parentheses.

Comment: Unfortunately, I need exactly this kind of fractions with parentheses.

Comment: @daleif -- To my surprise, your idea works.  Very nicely, in fact.  I don't remember seeing this documented anywhere, so you maybe should post an answer.